# WPF Business application form development

Tags: c#, wpf, printdocument

I volunteer at a local food pantry.  Currently we have an application for that we manually fill out with some detail information,  I know that I can develop a WPF application to collect the necessary data.  We are required to keep physical copies of the application as well.  Is it possible to create a duplicate of out application form that I can populate with the data collected and then print it?  What would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: Are you sure you need WPF for this? You could get something shipped much quicker if you used MS Access Forms integrated with Word's Mail-merge features for print copies - as a bonus it means users can use their existing knowledge of Office programs and in the event you can't work on it anymore there are plenty of other Office-capable devs who can maintain it in future.

Comment: I note that coming up with printed documents manually (i.e. using GDI, or generating printer commands in PCL or PostScript directly) is incredibly cumbersome and rarely used anymore - most programs I've seen that print output will either use MS Word (again, often using Mail-merge) or generate a HTML+CSS and print with WebKit - or use iTextSharp to generate a PDF directly.

Comment: I was thinking of using WPF for this as it would allow me to also add the data to our database. I was having a hard time finding, without buying it, to do this.

Comment: WPF has absolutely nothing to do with databases.

Comment: I know it mitt directly tied to databases but I already have an application for tracking our organizations and client's information, so I have the database code already built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a clean was to print the the Page or Window layout that I am aware of.

Two options that I am aware of

- Just use text with spaces and line breaks and send the text to the
  printer
- For more formatting create a FlowDocument and send that to the
  printer